# Route [bodegas/indtipo] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo definidas las rutas:

```php
Route::get('bodegas/indtipo','bodegaController@indtipo')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('bodegas','bodegaController')->middleware('auth');
```

al introducir directamente al navegador la ruta `proyecto/bodegas/indtipo`
fuciona perfectamente
pero cuando en la vista quiero que corra el código:

```php
<a href="{{route('bodegas/indtipo')}}">Tipo</a>
```

me da el error:

> Route [bodegas/indtipo] not defined.

Comment: A que codigo te refieres en la vista? Puedes enseñarnos la vista que cargas?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el helper route() se utiliza para cuando le asignas un nombre a la ruta, no para llamar su url.

Ejemplo:

```
Route::get('bodegas/indtipo','bodegaController@indtipo')->middleware('auth')->name('rutaIndtipo');
```

Si defino la ruta de la forma que explico arriba, puedo usar el helper route para llamarla por su nombre:

```
route('rutaIndtipo')
```

Sin embargo, teniendo en cuenta que no le asignaste un nombre, no podrás utilizar este helper, pero puedes utilizar el helper url en la vista:

```
url('bodegas/indtipo')
```

A continuación la documentación de ambos helpers:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url

Comment: Muchas gracias, le puse nombre a la ruta definida y funciono el link en la vista como me lo indicaste

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score -1):

te recomiendo eliminar la primera ruta que muestras, ya que cuando declaras un `Route::resource` generas todas las rutas que puede tener.

Por ejemplo si yo genero:

```
Route::resource('historial', 'HistorialController');
```

y por terminar escribo `php artisan route:list`
me va a mostrar lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera URI habla de **historial**, su nombre es **historial.index** y el controlador hace referencia al HistorialController@index. el controlador tiene que tener lo siguiente:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HistorialController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('historial.index');
    }
}
```

Ese return quiere decir que debes tener una carpeta llamada **historial** dentro de **resources** con un archivo **index.blade.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para este caso la dirección debería ser `http://homestead.test/historial` y te la debería mostrar. Revisa estas cosas y ve si te corre.

Saludos

Comment: Es incorrecto lo planteado en esta respuesta, un resource no genera TODAS las rutas que se pueden tener, tan solo genera las del CRUD, pero yo puedo crear todas las rutas que desee apuntando a otros métodos o a vistas o closures o lo que quiera.